# $ \int_{\mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d}b(x,y)\,f(x)\,f(y)dx\,dy \leq ||b_+||_{L^2(\mathbb R^d\times \mathbb R^d)}||f||_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}^2 $

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, functional-inequalities

We are given the following,
$$
b:\mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R,\;\; f:\mathbb R^d\rightarrow \mathbb R
$$
and
$$
f\in L^2(\mathbb R^d)\; ,\;b\in L^2(\mathbb R^d\times \mathbb R^d)
$$

Show that

$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d}b(x,y)\,f(x)\,f(y)dx\,dy\;\leq\;||b_+||_{L^2(\mathbb R^d\times \mathbb R^d)}||f||_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}^2
$$

Here $b_+(x,y)= max \{b(x,y),0\}$
i.e. positive part of function $b$.

Sorry for this trivial question, I see it should not be too difficult to ask here. But I cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since $b = b_{+} - b_{-}$ and $b_{-}$ is nonnegative, $b \le b_{+}$. Therefore

\begin{align}\int_{\Bbb R^d} \int_{\Bbb R^d} b(x,y)f(x)f(y)\, dx\, dy &\le \int_{\Bbb R^d} \int_{\Bbb R^d} b_{+}(x,y) |f(x)||f(y)|\, dx\, dy\\
& \le \|b_{+}\|_{L^2(\Bbb R^d\times \Bbb R^d)}\|f(x)f(y)\|_{L^2(\Bbb R^d\times \Bbb R^d)}\\
&= \|b_{+}\|_{L^2(\Bbb R^d \times \Bbb R^d)}\|f\|_{L^2(\Bbb R^d)}^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does the first inequality come from?

Comment: can you justify first inequality, I guess f needs to be a positive function for that to be true. Or is there some other justification which I do not know.

Comment: I had the same problem. $f(x)f(y)$ might be negative, doesn't it?

Comment: You could just use $\big| \int \int k(x,y) \, dx \, dy \big| \leq \int\int |k(x,y)| \, dx\, dy$. Then continue (with slight changes) with your proof as written.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that if b is a.e.positive, then the left handside integral is nonnegative.
This is trivial since b is a positive kernel of a Hilbert-Schimict operator, which is positive improving.

Comment: I do not see why the Positivity improving Kernels give rise to Postitive operators.